# Iterating through a CSV and assigning to Dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozzRF.jpg) except obviously bigger. What I need to do is iterate through the whole CSV and assign each individual person to their own dictionary and then create a list of those dictionaries. I've been chipping away at this and I need some guidance and help. Here is what I have so far:

```
with open('filename.csv', mode ='r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
        for row in itertools.islice(lvr, 0, 3):
            #here is where I am stuck
```

So basically this is what is hard for me to figure out:

1. How do I take that information and put it in it's own dictionary with keys like 'name', 'address', 'city', 'date', and 'amount'?
2. How do you step 3 lines every time?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: Does your csv have headers with the dictionary key names?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

Each row will be a dictionary already. You can store however you wish (append them to a list, etc.)

It will use the first row as the dictionary keys. If your csv doesn't have fieldnames in the first row.  You can pass them manually to the DictReader

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['first_name', 'last_name'])
```

---

To iterate by every 3rd line

```
for row in itertools.islice(reader, 0, None, 3):
    ...
```